# Zend routing without controller and action

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, routes, url-routing

There are given article URLs in a database (e.g. "article1", "article2", "article3").

When I type www.example.com/article1 I want to route to
controller: index,
action:index.

My route is:

```
//Bootstrap.php
public function _initRoute(){    
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    $router = $frontController->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('index',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('article1', array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index'
        ))
    );
}
```

But when I click on another link (functional before), I get www.example.com/article1 again.
Is there any way to do this route generally for all URLs in database? Something like:

```
    $router->addRoute('index',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':article', array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index'
        ))
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set up an ini file instead of going the xml route or "new Zend_controller_Router_Route" way. In my opinion its a little easier to organize. This is how I do what you are looking for. I recommend that make some changes to your routing and not use a route of http://domain.com/article1 but more like http://domain.com/article/1. either way here is what I would do in your situation.

In your routes.ini file

```
routes.routename.route = "route"
routes.routename.defaults.module = en
routes.routename.defaults.controller = index
routes.routename.defaults.action = route-name
routes.routename.defaults.addlparam = "whatevs"

routes.routename.route = "route2"
routes.routename.defaults.module = en
routes.routename.defaults.controller = index
routes.routename.defaults.action = route-name
routes.routename.defaults.addlparam = "whatevs2"

routes.route-with-key.route = "route/:key"
routes.route-with-key.defaults.module = en
routes.route-with-key.defaults.controller = index
routes.route-with-key.defaults.action = route-with-key
```

In your bootstrap file

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

#... other init things go here ...

protected function _initRoutes() {

    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini');
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $router->addConfig($config,'routes');
    $front->setRouter($router);
    return $router;

    }

}
```

In your controller you can then do this

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function routeNameAction () {
        // do your code here.
        $key = $this->_getParam('addlparam');

    }

    public function routeWithKeyAction () {

        $key = $this->_getParam('key');

        // do your code here.

    }
}
```

Comment: It is not what I am looking for. Could you edit your post without parameter "key"? Example URLs: www.example.com/new-article, www.example.com/best-article ... Only one "parameter" is at the end of www.example.com/

Comment: that's what the first block is in the *.ini section you can create as many of these "routes" as you need. if you need to pass in additional parameters you can as well in these blocks 


routes.routename.defaults.addlparam = "what ever you want";

you can then access these params as well. this way you can have  multiple routes pointing to one controller.